# Check if input value is less than x if so change it to x in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to change my input value to 1 if user changes it to anything less than 1. It should work every time the value is being changed. So far I can change the value to 1 unconditionally:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input[type=text]').val('1');
});
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the `change` event and an `if` statement for this.

The following code can be read as *"When the value of myInput changes, if the value of myInput is less than one, set the value of myInput to 1"*

```
jQuery('input[type=text]').on('change', function () {
    var myInput = jQuery(this);

    if (myInput.val() < 1) {
        myInput.val('1');
    }
});
```

Example:

```js
jQuery('input[type=text]').on('change', function () {
    var myInput = jQuery(this);

    if (myInput.val() < 1) {
        myInput.val('1');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
```

Comment: thanks, I wonder how can this: var myInput = jQuery(this);
be read, what does it do?

Comment: That is just caching the input in a variable so that jQuery doesn't have to find it twice. Every time you run `jQuery('input[type=text]')`, jQuery has to search through the entire document to find the element. If you store the result in a variable, the lookup only has to happen once.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the `change` event of your input.

```
jQuery('input[type=text]').on('change', function () {
    if (jQuery(this).val() < 1) {
        jQuery(this).val('1');
    }
}
```

But perhaps you want to use `<input type="number" min="1">` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener for `change` or `keyup` on the input itself.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myval').on('change', function() {
    // allow minimum of 1
    $(this).val(Math.max($(this).val(), 1))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myval" value="1" />
```

Though in your specific case, you could just have a `number` type input and add the `min` attribute to it to achieve the same result:

```html
<input type="number" id="myval" value="1" min="1" />
```